# C - Inserting into linked list in ascending order

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to create a program that inserts numbers into a linked list in ascending order. This is my insert function. It works for inserting some numbers but not others. I think it has something to do with the last part, but i cant figure it out.

```
node* insert(node* head, int value) {

    //check if head hasn't been created
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(head == NULL) {
            printf("Failed to create head node");
            return head;
        }
        head->value = value;
        head->next = NULL;
        return head;
    }

    //create a new node
    node *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(newNode == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to create node");
        return newNode;
    }
    newNode->value = value;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    //see if new node should be placed before head
    if (value < head->value) {
        newNode->next = head;
        return newNode;
    }

    //search through to find correct spot and insert the node
    node *temp = NULL;
    temp = head;
    while(temp->next != NULL && temp->value < value) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    newNode->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = newNode;
    return head;

}
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of input which behaves as expected as well as input which does not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the following bad

```
//search through to find correct spot and insert the node
node *temp = NULL;
temp = head;
while(temp->next != NULL && temp->value < value) {
    temp = temp->next;
}
newNode->next = temp->next;
temp->next = newNode;
```

e.g. to fix like this:

```
node *temp ,*prev;
temp = head;
while(temp != NULL && temp->value <= value) {
    prev = temp;
    temp = temp->next;
}
newNode->next = temp;
prev->next = newNode;
```

or

```
node *temp ,*prev;
temp = head->next;
prev = head;
while(temp != NULL && temp->value < value) {
    prev = temp;
    temp = temp->next;
}
newNode->next = temp;
prev->next = newNode;
```

Comment: Hello, would you mind to explain a little bit on the last part of your code? I get a little but confused by looking at it. So basically you are assigning head pointer as prev and head next pointer as temp. Then for the while loop, you are looping thru the linked list and comparing the value, if value is smaller, you insert it and update the pointer nodes. Then if the value is larger, you adding it via the code after the while loop?

Comment: yes. e.g list:{1,2,2,3,3,4}, value:3 (case 1) {1,2,2,3,3,<insert this>, 4} (case 2) {1,2,2,<insert this>, 3,3,4}.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `temp->next->value` inside the last while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This code of mine works perfectly.

void insertInAscOrder(int val) 
{
    node *new1;
    node *temp;
    node *previous; 

    //create new node
    new1 = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node)); 

    //check whether node is created or not
    if(new1 == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Insufficient memory.");
        return;
    }   

    //Updating different parts of the node
    new1 -> info = val;
    new1 -> next = NULL;    

    //checking whether the node created is only node or not
    if (start == NULL) 
    {       
        start = new1;
    } 
    //If value is less than the value of first node
    else if(val < start -> info) 
    {
        new1 -> next = start;
        start = new1;
    } 
    else 
    {   
        previous = start;
        temp = start -> next;


            //Go to the position where node is to be inserted
            while(temp != NULL && val > temp -> info) 
            {
                previous = temp;
                temp = temp -> next;
            }


            //Insert the node at particular position
           if(temp == NULL) 
           {
                   previous -> next = new1;
           } 
           else 
           {
                   new1 -> next = temp;
               previous -> next = new1;
           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better if you firstly implement (and test) functions like: `push_front()`, `insert()` (insert before), and `push_back()`, (probably `advance (Node* curr, int steps);`) and then simply take into consideration all the possibilities of insertion, i.e.:

- empty list (current node is first, so just `push_front / back()`)
- iterate (`advance()`) over all elements from `head` and on, till:

  - element with value larger than the new is found, `insert()` before it.
  - last element reached, `push_back()`.

in your new function `insert_ordered()`.