# Sorting a linked list with the insert method

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, boolean

This is my code,for practice and just educational purpose I would like to know how to insert in an ascending order.For example I input Andy,Berta,Aaron; and the output should be Aaron,Andy,Berta. What changes do I need to make to my code to get make implent this.Thank you!

```
public boolean insert(Person person) {

    Node n = new Node(person);

    if (head == null) {
        head = n;
        size++;
        return true;
    }

    Node current = head;
    Node prev = null;
    int comparison;

    while (current != null) {
        comparison = person.name.compareTo(current.person.name);
        if (comparison == 0) {
            return false;
        } else if (comparison > 0) { 

            if (current.next == null) { 
                current.next = n;
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        } else { 
            if (prev == null) { 
                Node oldHead = head;
                head = n;
                head.next = oldHead;
                break;
            }
            prev.next = n;
            n.next = current;
            break;
        }
        prev = current;
        current = current.next;
    }
    size++;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem in this code?

Comment: The output of the people is not in ascendind order; meaning that In what order I input the people that is how they will come out, the goal is that they come alphabeticly correct (A first,than B) etc..

Comment: Please share Person class also

Comment: https://pastebin.com/A1Vyb5aF for some reason I cannot edit it in the post.Here it is if you can edit it in please do so!

Comment: You can take reference from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788598/c-inserting-into-linked-list-in-ascending-order

Comment: Okay I've read the post.This is a diffrent programming language (C I pressume) so the syntax is a bit diffrent but if I'm getting this right there is a problem with my else loop?